# How to add jQuery UI Button icons to input buttons?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

Is it possible to use [jQuery UI Button icons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons) with `<input type="submit">` elements?

The documentation example uses `<button>` elements, but it does not explicitly say whether or not icons work with input buttons. I'd like to add icons to ASP.NET Button controls which render as `<input type="submit">`.

This is what I've tried:

```
$("input.add").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus" } });
```

The button is styled correctly except for the missing icon. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing it right.  It just does not seem to work on input elements.  A cursory look at the source code for JQuery UI Button shows that it prepends `<span class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon " + icons.primary + "'></span>` to the element getting the icon but this does not seem to happen on input elements.

Actually looked a bit closer.  Not sure how I missed this the first time but the source contains the following:

```
if ( this.type === "input" ) {
  if ( this.options.label ) {
    this.element.val( this.options.label );
  }
  return;
}
```

Which basically tells the code to exit before the span is prepended/appended on input elements.  So this is by design.

Answer (score 11):

As Bradley Mountford states, Submit elements are not styled with icons by design (why that's the design, I have no idea).

Change your asp:Button to a asp:LinkButton and all is right in the world. Yep, it really is that easy.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was overwritten styles, so this solution helped me:

```
$('input.add').each(function(){
          $(this).replaceWith('<button  class="add" type="' + $(this).attr('type') + '">' + $(this).val() + '</button>');
});
$('.add').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-circle-plus' } });
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm looking for this solution and i found my one that works perfect

javascript

```
$(function () {

    //botoes de login

    $("#btnLogin").button({
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-key" }
        }).hide().after('<button>').next().button({
            icons:
            {
                primary: 'ui-icon-key'
            },
            label: $("#btnLogin").val()
        }).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).prev().click();
        });
    $("#close").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-close" } });
});
```

webform

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation for what this is doing?

Comment: The js  is to use the custom jquery ui theme and whith an icon in asp.net button btnLogin

Comment: +1 this helped me greatly.  None of the previous answers worked as intended.  Not sure why they didn't work, but this one did.