# Change view on button click with javascript parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Say I have the following button

```
<button id="CopyUsersRolesButton" type="button" onclick="CopyUsersRoles()" data-url="@Url.Action("CopyUsersRoles", "Index", new {userId = "0" })">
                  Copy Users Roles</button>
```

I want to redirect to a view that is returned by the following action:

```
    public ActionResult CopyUsersRoles(int userId)
    {
        var model = new CopyUsersRolesViewModel
        {
            SelectedUserId = userId
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

I need to pass a javascript variable (`SelectedUserId`) to the action.

The only way I've got it to work is by keeping a placeholder in the URL.Action method and replacing it as follows:

```
function CopyUsersRoles() {
    var url = $('#CopyUsersRolesButton').data('url');
    window.open(url.replace('0', SelectedUserId));       
    return false;
}
```

This feels very hacky to me, is there not a cleaner solution? I don't currently have a form on the html page and would like to avoid using an input button as all the other buttons have Jquery UI icons (see [How to add jQuery UI Button icons to input buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822891/how-to-add-jquery-ui-button-icons-to-input-buttons)).

Comment: I think you are doing right, because you are sending the javascript variable to the new request. If you do not want to use button then  you may use any HTML control, because using javascript/jquery you may fireup event that will going to ask sever for new view.

Comment: Could you use `<input type="submit" />` instead, or does the form submit somewhere else?

Comment: @AJ I don't want to use <input type='submit' /> because its unfortunately not possible to style the button with a jQuery UI icon